# Why do I get the error "... version `Qt_5.8' not found ..." when trying to run "4k Video Downloader"?

Tags: software-installation

**Summary**

1. I've just installed the 32-bit version of the "4k Video Downloader" package
into /opt/4kvideodownloader/

using the instructions at

https://www.click4infos.com/install-4k-video-downloader/

The main steps that I followed on that webpage are 4 and 8. As instructed, I
have put the downloaded and unzipped directories and files in

/opt/4kvideodownloader/

2. a) But when I run 4kvideodownloader, I get the following error:

```
$ /opt/4kvideodownloader/4kvideodownloader-bin
/opt/4kvideodownloader/4kvideodownloader-bin:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sse2/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.8' not found
(required by /opt/4kvideodownloader/4kvideodownloader-bin)
/opt/4kvideodownloader/4kvideodownloader-bin:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sse2/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.8' not found
(required by /opt/4kvideodownloader/libQt5Script.so.5)
/opt/4kvideodownloader/4kvideodownloader-bin:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sse2/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.8' not found
(required by /opt/4kvideodownloader/libQt5Widgets.so.5)
/opt/4kvideodownloader/4kvideodownloader-bin:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sse2/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.8' not found
(required by /opt/4kvideodownloader/libQt5Xml.so.5)
$
```

b) Also, "$ konsole" will no longer launch from a terminal, but gives similar
output to the above ("a)"). See Full Details "6.".

3. I wondered if doing step "8" of the "www.click4infos.com" instructions at "1."
above has caused the problem. Step 8 says

> Add the program libraries to the system;
>
> $ sudo ldconfig /opt/4kvideodownloader/

**4. My Question:**

I'm out of my depth with this, so could you tell me what is wrong, and what I
need to do to make 4kvideodownloader run OK (and make "konsole" launch as it
did before)?

**Full Details**

5. I downloaded the 32-bit 4kvideodownloader from

https://downloads2.4kdownload.com/app/4kvideodownloader_4.3_i386.tar.bz2

6. Launching "konsole" from a terminal worked fine before installing
4kvideodownloader. But now, I get an error similar to the one that occurs when
running 4kvideodownloader, as follows:

```
$ konsole
konsole: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sse2/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.8' not
found (required by /opt/4kvideodownloader/libQt5Widgets.so.5)
konsole: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sse2/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.8' not
found (required by /opt/4kvideodownloader/libQt5DBus.so.5)
konsole: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sse2/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.8' not
found (required by /opt/4kvideodownloader/libQt5Xml.so.5)
$
```

7. I'm wondering if the error at "2.a)" in the Summary, namely "version `Qt_5.8'
not found" is a red herring. This is because I THOUGHT I'd seen a library name
relating to 4kvideodownloader of something like  libQt5Core.so.5.6  somewhere on
my filesystem. I believe that the appended ".6" is the so-called "minor number".

So wouldn't this suggest that the libraries supplied with the 4kvideodownloader
installation are Qt version 5.6 (ie correct), and not 5.8?

8. /opt/4kvideodownloader/  contains

```
$ ls -1 --indicator-style=slash --group-directories-first /opt/4kvideodownloader

audio/
doc/
imageformats/
platforminputcontexts/
platforms/
translation/
xcbglintegrations/
4kvideodownloader-bin
4kvideodownloader.sh
libavcodec.so.56
libavformat.so.56
libavutil.so.54
libcrypto.so.1.0.0
libicudata.so.52
libicui18n.so.52
libicuuc.so.52
libmp3lame.so.0
libportaudio.so.2
libQt5Concurrent.so.5
libQt5Core.so.5
libQt5DBus.so.5
libQt5Gui.so.5
libQt5Script.so.5
libQt5ScriptTools.so.5
libQt5Widgets.so.5
libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
libQt5Xml.so.5
libssl.so.1.0.0
libswresample.so.1
libswscale.so.3
libx264.so.148
$
```

9. The config files related to "ldconfig" are as follows:

```
$ ls -1 --indicator-style=slash --group-directories-first /etc/ld.so.conf*

/etc/ld.so.conf

/etc/ld.so.conf.d:
atlas.conf
fakeroot-i386-linux-gnu.conf
i386-linux-gnu.conf
libc.conf
zz_amd64-biarch-compat.conf
zz_x32-biarch-compat.conf
$
```

All the above files (in this entry "9.") have old modification dates, so it
appears that they have not been modified/created as a result of running
ldconfig.

10. A website says that the following tells me what my **version** of Qt is:

```
$ qmake --version
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.7 in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
$
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You are getting that error message because it's proprietary software compiled and linked against a version of Qt that you do not have installed on your system.  This kind of thing will **always** be a problem with software that is not compiled for the exact version of the distribution you are running, and it will always be a **recurring** problem - updates to either the proprietary program or the distribution or both can cause it to break at any time.

   It seems as if you have Qt 4.8.7 installed, and the version of "4k Video Downloader" you are trying to install requires Qt 5.8.  Either try to find an older version of 4K Video Downloader to install, or upgrade your distribution to a version that provides Qt 5.8.

   Open Source software, by way of contrast, can be recompiled as needed to run on any version of any distribution that meets the minimum requirements, and/or modified as needed to do so.  Not only *can be* recompiled, but generally *is*.   Aside from the ethical advantages of free software vs proprietary software this is one of the most important pragmatic reasons why many Free Software and Open Source users prefer to avoid proprietary software.

   Another major reason is that free software is far less likely to be spyware or some other kind of malware.  While Free and Open Source software isn't 100% trustworthy (nothing is), it **can** be examined, modified, and forked if necessary.  Proprietary software can't be.
2. I recommend using [youtube-dl](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/) if you need software to download videos from youtube and/or many other sites.

   `youtube-dl` is a command-line tool, but if you need a GUI interface to it, you could look at [youtubedl-gui](https://github.com/JaGoLi/ytdl-gui)....I've never used the GUI so I don't know if it's any good or not.

   There's also a fork of `youtube-dl` called [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) which claims to have additional features and fixes.  They say *"yt-dlp is a youtube-dl fork based on the now inactive youtube-dlc. The main focus of this project is adding new features and patches while also keeping up to date with the original project"*.  Again, I've never used this, so I don't know what improvements it offers.

   `youtube-dl` itself (and probably all three programs) should be available as packages for most distributions.  Which means they'll be easy to install and likely kept up-to-date as new versions of both youtube-dl (etc) and the distributions are released.

Comment: PART 1 of 2: Thanks very much cas. I've been using youtube-dl for a long time,
but in recent months, the download speed has been throttled (by youtube I
believe) to about 50 kbps. That's why I had to look for another downloader. See
the following site for the youtube-dl (or yt-dlp?) throttle situation:
https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/issues/964 The last post there shows that
the throttling still persists as at 15nov21. ...

Comment: PART 2 of 2: ... I've installed yt-dlp but it WON'T WORK. It needs Python
3.6+, but my repo only goes up to ver 2.7.11-2. A user reported alarming
consequences to his system when trying to install 3.6+.

Comment: I think it may be time you updated your install if you can.

Answer (score 0):

This app provides it's own QT5 libs, and the environment has to be setup correctly.

This is wrong:

`sudo ln -sf /opt/4kvideodownloader/4kvideodownloader-bin /usr/bin/4kvideodownloader`

It should be:

`sudo ln -sf /opt/4kvideodownloader/4kvideodownloader.sh /usr/bin/4kvideodownloader`

Notice the lack of `-bin` and the addition of `.sh`. The `.sh` file setups the correct `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for it run.

You also should not have done `sudo ldconfig /opt/4kvideodownloader/`. Hopefully a reboot will cure that.

Comment: Many thanks Bib. 1. The correct command you gave me now makes
4kvideodownloader run. 2. However, when I paste a youtube link into
4kvideodownloader, an error message says "Can't parse this link. Please send it
to our support and we'll check it."

Comment: Re "You also should not have done sudo ldconfig /opt/4kvideodownloader/":
Unfortunately after a reboot, I still get the error message "version `Qt_5.8'
not found" when launching "$ konsole" from a terminal. As a result, I can't open
a konsole terminal to do Bash command-line work.

Comment: PART 1 of 3: HELP! I've just discovered that there are other programs that I run
from a terminal that are giving the error message "version `Qt_5.8' not found".
It means that those programs don't run - at all. I'm worried because I'LL NO
DOUBT SOON DISCOVER MANY PROGRAMS THAT I CAN'T RUN ANYMORE because of this
condition! ...

Comment: PART 2 of 3: ... For example, when I run "$ kompare", it gives similar error
messages to when I run "$ konsole". Any argument* that I add to "$ kompare" just
results in the same error messages. (*Including nonsense arguments like "$
kompare -----bananas".) ...

Comment: PART 3 of 3: ... Is some aspect of Qt intercepting things when I run such as "$
kompare", and are the error messages due to Qt not being happy with an
unsatisfied entry in one of its config files re 4kvideodownloader?

I would be most grateful if you could suggest how I fix the problem.

Comment: First, login from the console as root via `CTRL-ALT-F1` and run `ldconfig` by itself and if that does not work `ldconfig -v` and post the output. Switch back to the gui via `ALT-f8`. Second, when you run the command, put the URL inside quotes.

Comment: PART 1 of 2: Your kind instructions to run ldconfig by itself in virtual
terminal 1 worked! Both "$ konsole" and "$ kompare" now run OK (with no error
messages). You're brilliant! ...

Comment: PART 2 of 2: ... I wasn't sure what command you meant by "when you run the
command, put the URL ...", so I guessed you meant run (for example) "$
4kvideodownloader 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0i7Xb5mwFlM'". When I did
this, I got the same message "Can't parse this link. Please send it to our
support and we'll check it." I wonder if this is an old version of 32-bit
4kvideodownloader that somehow doesn't handle current youtube URLs. I'll see if
www.4kdownload.com offer any support.

Comment: I assume it should be `4kvideodownloader 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0i7Xb5mwFlM'`.

Comment: Yes, sorry Bib, it must have been a mis-paste. I did use `4kvideodownloader 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0i7Xb5mwFlM'`.